# Transact SQL: selecting a boolean expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ReportInvoked , EmailSent
  FROM tblReportInvoker 
 WHERE WebUserId = 12345
```

This gives me two bit values. What I really want is a scalar result that is the logical AND of these two values. Is this possible? This seems like it would be easy but I'm not finding a syntax that will work.

Edit: Of course the flaw in my clever plan is that it will be true if both processes fail, so revised query to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 (ReportInvoked & EmailSent) & (1 & ReportInvoked) AS 'ReportSent'
FROM tblReportInvoker 
WHERE WebUserId = 12345
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 ReportInvoked & EmailSent AS ReportSent FROM tblReportInvoker WHERE WebUserId = 12345
```

[Bitwise AND operator in Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I was sure I had tried this, but evidently not... Putting out too many fires today.

Comment: @tvanfosson there you go, bro